# Two-Photon Transitions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

I'm reading these course notes on two-photon transitions at http://cua.mit.edu/8.421_S06/Chapter9.pdf

But I can't understand why it looks like they do not allow for Autler-Townes splitting. In section 9.3.1, he derives a two-photon transition probability. It looks like a single-peaked function of the detuning. Shouldn't we also be able to look at this problem in a dressed state picture and see such a splitting?

Comment: maybe he assumes weak coupling(Rabi frequencies smaller than linewidth)? that way there should be no splitting.